# Combining SpecFlow table and Moq mocked object

Tags: c#, moq, specflow

I have a situation where I want to use a mocked object (using Moq) so I can create setup and expectations, but also want to supply some of the property values using the SpecFlow Table. Is there a convenient way to create a mock and supply the table for the seed values?

```
// Specflow feature

Scenario Outline: MyOutline
Given I have a MyObject object as
| Field | Value     |
| Title | The Title |
| Id    | The Id    |


// Specflow step code    

Mock<MyObject> _myMock;

[Given(@"I have a MyObject object as")]
public void GivenIHaveAMyObjectObjectAs(Table table)
{
   var obj = table.CreateInstance<MyObject>();

   _myMock = new Mock<MyObject>();

   // How do I easily combine the two?

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an overload of `CreateInstance` which takes a `Func<T> methodToCreateTheInstance`. You can use it to pass an already setup mock as the base for the speclow `CreateInstance` method:

```cs
[Given(@"I have a MyObject object as")]
public void GivenIHaveAMyObjectObjectAs(Table table)
{
   _myMock = new Mock<MyObject>();
   //you need to do all the setup before passing _myMock to table.CreateInstance
   _myMock.Setup(o => o.SomeProperty).Returns("someValue"); 

   var obj = table.CreateInstance<MyObject>(() => _myMock.Object);

   _myMock.VerifySet(foo => foo.Title = "The Title");
}
```

Comment: I like that. A lot! Thanks

Comment: Nice, but don't you need to call myMock.SetupAllProperties() ? At least for interface and abstract only definitions.

Comment: @AlSki thanks for the additional info and depending on the OPs needs a `_myMock.SetupAllProperties()` could be necessary but without knowing how a concrete `MyObject` looks like it is just guessing. And anyway the question was about how to combine moq and Specflow not about how to properly setup properties in moq.

Answer (score 3):

If the object wasn't mocked you would simply use the assist helpers (See https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers) but since you need the call to Setup(...) then it won't work.

However you can also use StepArgumentTransformation like this

```
    [StepArgumentTransformation]
    public Mock<MyData> MockMyDataTransform(Table table)
    {
        MyData myData = new Mock<MyData>();
        var row = table.Rows[0];
        if (table.ContainsColumn("MyField"))
        {
            myData.Setup(x=>x.MyField).Returns(row["MyField"]);
        }
     ....
    }
```

and use it with

```
    [Given(@"something like:")]
    private void GivenSomethingLike(Mock<MyData> myData)
    ....
```